# Why the print_r() function is disturbing the program output?

Tags: php, arrays, post, submit, form-submit

I've written following HTML code in a file titled `file_upload_form.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the file titled `upload.php` contains following code :

```
<?php
  echo "Value of Post is : ".print_r($_POST); die;
?>
```

When I run this code in a web browser (i.e. submitted the HTML form by clicking on Submit button) I got following output :

```
Array ( [submit] => Upload Image ) Value of Post is : 1
```

Please refer the concerned:

[image: screen shot of output window]

How the output of `print_r()` function got printed before the string **"Value of Post is : "** and my next question is from where the value 1 got printed after the string **"Value of Post is : "**?

I mean why such discrepancy is there in the program output? Why the string **"Value of Post is : "** is not getting first and then the values in the array `$_POST`? Why **1** is getting printed and from where it is coming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print_r()` prints its result itself, by default.

This line :

```
echo "Value of Post is : ".print_r($_POST); die;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. When it's interpreted, it calls `print_r`, which prints its output, then your `echo` prints the string `echo "Value of Post is : "` followed by the return of your `print_r()`. Since it returns nothing, only the string is returned.

But their is a way to make it to work exactly the way you assumed it works. [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.print-r.php) takes a second argument, which is set to `false` by default :

```
mixed print_r ( mixed $expression \[, bool $return = false \] )
```

Setting this argument to `true` makes `print_r` to not print its output itself and to return it as a string instead :

```
echo "Value of Post is : ".print_r($_POST, true); die;
```

As a tip, and in case you don't already know, you can also frame your `print_r` call with `<pre>` tags so that it's formatted. It will make it more readable, especially for big or multidimensional arrays :

```
echo '<pre>Value of Post is : ', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>'; die;
```

Comment: If such is the case when I execute the code print_r($_FILES); die; it didn't printed out "1". It only printed the array elements. Why it didn't print "1" as I didn't provide any additional parameter to the print_r() function?

Comment: @user2839497 As I said, print_r prints its output by itself, that why it's named that way. If you try to put it in an `echo`, it will echo '1' because print_r returns `true` when it doesn't return its output.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass true as the second argument to `print_r` if you want it to return instead of directly output in

```
echo "Value of Post is : ".print_r($_POST); die;
```

Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php:

> **return**
>
> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.

When you do not set the second parameter to `true`, PHP will first execute `print_r` and immediately dump the variable to STDOUT. The return value of `print_r` will then be a boolean `true`. The boolean will get concatenated and then printed. The `true` type juggles to "1" in a string context, hence "Value of Post is: 1".

Comment: If such is the case when I execute the code print_r($_FILES); die; it didn't printed out "1". It only printed the array elements. Why it didn't print "1" as I didn't provide any additional parameter to the print_r() function?

Comment: @user2839497 when you do `print_r($_FILES)` the return value is not used, hence no 1 printed. When you do `echo print_r($_FILES)`, it will first dump the array and then print the return value, e.g. 1.